# Rotate video SurfaceView inside a ViewPage

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a SurfaceView as display to a MediaPlayer, but the video is sideways and I need to rotate it. I tried using `SurfaceView.setRotation(90)` but this gave me a black View.

If I set the rotation to any degree lower than 90, the video translates to the right (being pushed behind the content of the other page in the ViewPage) by a relative amount.

Here is the code I'm using to create the view and play the video:

```
final SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(getActivity());
surface.setRotation(90);

surface.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback(){
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mPlayer.setDisplay(surface);

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);

            mPlayer.setVideoScalingMode(MediaPlayer.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
     }

     @Override
     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         mPlayer.stop();
         mPlayer.release();
     }
});
```

As said, I'm adding the surface to a ViewPage. The video plays, and, aside from rotation, everything else works.

I tried `mPlayer.setSurface(holder.getSurface())` with the same results.

I tried using TextureView with limited success. It rotated, but I couldn't scale it and keep aspect ratio with cropping.

Tried locking the canvas and rotating the canvas of the holder, but all I've got was a black View, no matter what degree.

Comment: Your problem is that the `View` is rotating, but the surface to which the video is rendered is incapable of rotating in the same manner. Rotating the `View` only transforms the top left coordinate to where the surface is drawn, meaning the video is simply translated (eventually to an off-screen location). That may not be the most readily understandable concept, but it stems from the fact that `SurfaceView` is basically a hack. It's job is to cut a hole in the view hierarchy so that a drawing surface underneath is made visible.

Comment: I think you would be better served to post the `TextureView` code (which is fully integrated into the view hierarchy) and try to explain what problems you are having there.